# GnuCOBOL entry point not found

Tags: syntax, runtime-error, cobol, gnucobol

I've installed GnuCOBOL 2.2 on my Ubuntu 17.04 system. I've written a basic hello world program to test the compiler.

```
1       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
2       PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
3      *---------------------------
4       DATA DIVISION.
5      *---------------------------
6       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
7           DISPLAY 'Hello, world!'.
8           STOP RUN.
```

This program is entitled *HelloWorld.cbl*. When I compile the program with the command

```
cobc HelloWorld.cbl
```

HelloWorld.so is produced. When I attempt to run the compiled program using

```
cobcrun HelloWorld
```

I receive the following error:

```
libcob: entry point 'HelloWorld' not found
```

Can anyone explain to me what an entry point is in GnuCOBOL, and perhaps suggest a way to fix the problem and successfully execute this COBOL program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official manual of GNUCOBOL](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html#Hello-world_0021), you should compile your code with:

```
cobc -x HelloWorld.cbl
```

then run it with

```
./HelloWorld
```

You can also read [GNUCOBOL wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuCOBOL#Example_programs) which contains some exmaples for further information.

P.S. As Simon Sobisch said, If you change your file name to `HELLO-WORLD.cbl` to match the program ID, the same commands that you have used will be ok:

```
cobc HELLO-WORLD.cbl
cobcrun HELLO-WORLD
```

Comment: Note: this answer is not completely correct - the `-x` will work but it isn't the "way to compile according to the official docs", see provided answer. Nonetheless: thanks for digging into the documentation and providing an answer, +1

Comment: @SimonSobisch Thank you for your description of the compile process, but I meant to show him the way to compile *his* code", not the COBOL compilation in general. I just wanted to help him compile his Hello World example in the simplest manner.

Comment: the simplest matter is to use `HelloWorld` as `PROGRAM-ID` for his specific case ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone explain to me what an entry point is in GnuCOBOL, and perhaps suggest a way to fix the problem and successfully execute this COBOL program?

An entry point is a point where you may enter a shared object (this is actually more C then COBOL).
GnuCOBOL generates entry points for each `PROGRAM-ID`, `FUNCTION-ID` and `ENTRY`. Therefore your entry point is `HELLO-WORLD` (which likely gets a conversion as `-` is no valid identifier in ANSI C - you won't have to think about this when `CALL`ing a program as the conversion will be done internal).

Using `cobcrun` internally does:

1. search for a shared object (in your case `HelloWord`), as this is found (because you've generated it) it will be loaded
2. search for an entry point in all loaded modules - which isn't found

There are three possible options to get this working:

- As mentioned in Ho1's answer: use `cobc -x`, the reason that this works is because you don't generate a shared object at all but a C main which is called directly (= the entry point doesn't apply at all)
- preload the shared object and calling the program by its `PROGRAM-ID` (entry point), either manually with `COB_PRE_LOAD=HelloWorld cobcrun HELLO-WORLD` or through cobcrun (option available since GnuCOBOL 2.x) `cobcrun -M HelloWorld HELLO-WORLD`
- change the `PROGRAM-ID` to match the source name (either rename or change the source, I'd do the second: `PROGRAM-ID. HelloWorld.`)